# AngularJS how to get the number of days and hour between two dates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to calculate number of days and hours difference between 2 days in AngularJS

```
dueOnDate: "2017-05-30T08:30:10.123+02:00"

currentDate: "2016-05-30T09:30:10.123+02:00"
```

Is there any inbuilt Angular function to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do these types of questions come in batches? Perhaps [*Return Date in format ( x years, x months, x days)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189490/return-date-in-format-x-years-x-months-x-days-javascript) will help. Note that "2016-05-30T09:30:10.123+02:00" will not be correctly parsed by at least some implementations, you'll need to do it manually (or use a library).

Comment: Have a look at: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the input...Let me try this once.

Answer (score 2):

As [Robg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) said, you are currently dealing with a string which makes it more difficult to do calculations with. First thing I would do is start using the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library which is very good for working with dates.

Then I would have a look at this [question about hour difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623783/get-the-time-difference-between-two-datetimes) and the answers because I think they have everything in them you need.

An example is:

```
var then = "04/09/2013 15:00:00";
var now = "02/09/2013 14:20:30";

var duration = moment.duration(then.diff(now));
var hours = duration.asHours();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Daan, let me check this once.