# Javascript days between 2 dates return wrong

Tags: javascript, date, math

Been trying to resolve this one for a while with no success, I found couple of similar answers here, but the format is what is important here. I need to return X years, X months, X days.

Can you take a look to see, what I am doing wrong here... Number of days are not quite right.

Here is a [bin](http://jsbin.com/zarajomeho/edit?js,console)

```js
function inBetweenDays(y,m,d){

var user_date = new Date(y,m + 1,d);
var today_date = new Date();

  
var diff_date = (user_date - today_date);

var num_years = diff_date/31536000000;
var num_months = (diff_date % 31536000000)/2628000000;
var num_days =  ((diff_date % 31536000000) % 2628000000)/86400000;
 
var years = Math.floor(Math.abs(num_years));
var months = Math.floor(Math.abs(num_months));  
var days =  Math.floor(Math.abs(num_days));
  
  if (years >= 1) {
    console.log(years + " years " + months + " months " + days + " days");
  } else if (years <= 0 && months >= 0){
     console.log(months + " months " + days + " days");
   } else {
     console.log(days + " days ");
   }
  
  }
  

inBetweenDays(2015,03,04);
inBetweenDays(2016,03,04);
inBetweenDays(2016,02,04);
inBetweenDays(2018,02,04);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the third line be `new Date(y,m - 1,d)` instead?

Comment: You are going wrong already in assuming a day was `86400000` milliseconds long. Please go and research why.

Comment: @Nayuki... I think it should be m + 1, since month is 0 based.....

Comment: Are you looking for the _calendar_ difference between two dates? If you want  March 1 to be 2 months, 0 days after Jan 1 irrespective of leap year, it will be hard to use milliseconds between two dates to arrive at the answer.

Comment: @Lucky500 Just because is 0 based, you should use real month -1,and can get the true param month.But sadly it's not the only mistake.I think may be this concept is wrong, because `one day` is base on 24 hours is a certain value, but `month` and `year` a not certain collection about day, some month have different days and so does year. You have to consider it first.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will work on tweaking it a bit more.

Comment: Your result is almost certainly wrong for periods longer than a few months, since the length of days, months and years varies. Are you sure this isn't a duplicate of [*Return Date in format ( x years, x months, x days)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189490/return-date-in-format-x-years-x-months-x-days-javascript) (which is itself a duplicate)? You probably should zero the hours for *today_date*.

Comment: @CBroe a day **IS** 86400000 ms long.    Please go and research why.

Comment: @Charlie74—except when daylight saving starts or ends.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm to calculate the calendar date difference between two date in terms of years, months, days is as follows:

1. validate dates to have full years (4 digits), months in range 1-12, and month-day in range 1 - days in month of year of date.
2. subtract earlier date days from later date days. If borrow required, add days in the month of earlier date, *in the year of the earlier date*, to later date days and add 1 to months to be subtracted.
3. subtract earlier date month from later date months. If borrow required, add 12 to later day months and add 1 to years to be subtracted.
4. subtract earlier date year from later date year.

This may have been implemented in one existing answer to this question in a chain of duplicate questions, but try and spot it without documentation of the algorithm. The calculation of days to borrow can be calculated as follows:

```
function monthDays(y, m)    // full year and month in range 1-12
{   var leap = 0;
    if( m == 2)
    {   if( y % 4 == 0) leap = 1;
        if( y % 100 == 0) leap = 0;
        if( y % 400 == 0) leap = 1;
    }
    return [0, 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31][ m] + leap;
}
```

(Edit) or alternatively as per comment, using the behavior of Date objects adjusting to out of expected bound behavior:

```
function monthDays( y, m)
{ return new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
}
```

Comment: If *m* is calendar month number, then `new Date(y, m, 0).getDate()` returns the number of days in the month and is less to type. ;-)

Comment: @RobG I like it. Would I like to explain it to a novice?  ;-)

Comment: Using the calendar month number sets the date to the next month (since ECMAScript months are 0 based), but setting the date to zero creates a date for the last day of the previous month, so back to the month you want, e.g. `new Date(2016,1,0)` creates a date for 2016-01-31.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input id="first" value="1/1/2000"/>
<input id="second" value="1/1/2001"/>

<script>
  alert(datediff("day", first, second)); // what goes here?
</script>
```

JavaScript

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
```

Source:
[How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms);

    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms / ONE_DAY);
}
```

Comment: Or `Math.round((date1 - date2) / 8.64e7)`. Why not keep the sign?